# WooCommerce wc_price( $price ) & variations & headache

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I'm having beginner problems with some PHP...

I'd like to change the price label on a variable product depending on whether a product variation is rented or sold. Each product has both options.

I've realised that the product's post title includes the text 'rent' or 'buy' depending on the variation.

So I have butchered some code found here to try and display a different label depending on the results of the products post title. Currently looks like this (but doesn't work!), have a feeling that this is totally the wrong approach, can anyone help?

```
function sv_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) {

$is_rental = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'post_title' );
$price = $product->get_regular_price();

if (strpos($is_rental, "Rent") !== false) {
    $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $price ) . ' per week</span>';    
}
 else
 {
$price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $price ) . ' buy today</span>';
}

return $price_html;
}
```

Comment: Update, the variation text actually seems to be in post_excerpt, not post_title.. Still doesn't work though

Answer (score 1):

Probably a better approach would be to check for the accompanying product attribute which stores the values on bases which you have your variations ('rent'/'buy') and then carry out your business from there as this approach seems hacky and can fail if the store owner decides to change the way they name their products in future.

Also, you can get product properties like name (`$product->get_name()`), attribute (`$product->get_attribute(<attr_name>`)), etc., using the methods provided in the WooCommerce classes ([Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)/[Product Variation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variation.html))

Also, is your function hooked to the right filter?

Comment: Hacky is probably the right description! :-) It's hooked with > add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_html', 10, 2 );

Comment: If the function is hooked correctly but you still see no change then it means that your conditional blocks are not working. Try to return a static value at the end of the code (like `return '100';`) and see if it is reflected in the front end. Also, I would advice you to go with my suggested methodology because of problem with your approach that I previously stated.

Comment: I gave up and used this instead > https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-custom-field-product-variation/